# Doctrine query group by date

Tags: sql, zend-framework, doctrine

I am building an application and I want some sort of notification / log type of page intergrated where the user can see his activity. The page needs to look like the following example:

```
Today  
[Username] has done [activity] 13:20  
[Username] has done [activity]  11:27  
[Username] has done [activity]  10:53  

Yesterday   
[Username] has done [activity]  13:20  
[Username] has done [activity]  11:27  
[Username] has done [activity]  10:53  

14 februari  
[Username] has done [activity]  13:20  
[Username] has done [activity]  11:27  
[Username] has done [activity]  10:53
```

The thing is that I have absolutely no idea where to start. I am thinking of some kind of log table and then log everything that happens in a table. But how do I need to query to get the above result?
  I really need someone or something to point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

you are on the right direction :
Just create your log table like this:

```
create table log(
id int not null primary key identity(1,1),
userID int not null,
logdate datetime,
activityID int not null)
```

assuming you have a users table that contain the users and a Activity table that contains all the possible activities

then you can produce your query joining the 3 tables:

```
select * 
from log l 
     join UserTable u on l.userId=u.UserId 
     join ActivityTable a on l.ActivityId=a.ActivityID
```

and then format your text based on the select